# Running Specflow 3.0 reports on Nunit console

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

I just upgraded to Specflow 3.0 with NUnit as my test runner. Specflow 3.0 documentation indicates that reporting has been removed from Specflow 3.0 (https://specflow.org/documentation/Reporting/). It seems they have gotten rid of specflow.exe

In Specflow 2.x, I would execute reports by calling

```
specflow.exe nunitexecutionreport test.csproj /xmlTestResult:.\TestResults\TestResult.xml /out:.\TestResults\TestResult.html
```

I am at a loss as to how to run the nunit reports without calling specflow.exe. The Specflow website does not seem to have additional information how to run reports on Specflow 3.

Has anyone tried running reports on Specflow 3 and Nunit console?

Answer (score 0):

It's a crappy solution, but you can install both SpecFlow 2.4 and 3 and then use 3 to run the tests a 2.4 to generate the report.